# DB2 specific Stored Procedure tesing in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, stored-procedures, junit, db2

**Any Framework/Tool for testing the stored procedures by using JUnit?**

Working on to write the JUnit tests for Stored Procedure used in DB2 ddl file
The Stored procedure just having some SQL queries based code e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE POPULATE_C() 
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN 

    DECLARE NAM CHAR (54);
    DECLARE SNAM CHAR (54);
    DECLARE CAT CHAR (10);
    DECLARE END_T INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT NAM, SNAM, LPAD(' ',10)
        FROM MYTABLE

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET END_T = 1;

    OPEN C;

    FETCH FROM C INTO NAM, SNAM, CAT;

    WHILE END_T = 0 DO 
            INSERT INTO CON (X1, X2, X3) VALUES (NAM, SNAM, CAT);
            FETCH FROM C INTO NAM, SNAM, CAT;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE C;
    COMMIT;
END
```

> Tried **DBUnit**, but it doesn't support the stored procedures testing
>   on HSQLDB database, so how to test these functionality in JUnit.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Also tried Derby the so called DB2's language compatible as stated here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760471/is-there-a-good-in-memory-database-that-would-act-like-db2], but no result. Failing on create procedure statement.

Comment: What do you want to test in that procedure? BTW, I wrote db2unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More search given a name [DB2Unit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1501unittest-sql-db2/index.html) to do the required job.